# Replacing characters

Tags: java, loops, char

I have a String entered by the User.
 I'm trying to replace all non-uppercase letters(i.e. numbers, or symbols) with spaces without using methods such as `replace()`, `Stringbuilders`, or `arrays`.

This is what I have so far :

```
public static void formatPlaintext(String sentence){

  String sentenceUpper = sentence.toUpperCase();
  System.out.println(sentenceUpper);

  String emptyString = " ";
  for(int i = 0; i< sentenceUpper.length() ; i++){
      char ch = sentenceUpper.charAt(i);
      if(ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z'){
        ch = emptyString.charAt(0);
      }

    }

}//end of formatPlaintext
```

I keep getting the error that String index is out of range. I believe it has to do with :

```
ch = emptyString.charAt(0);
```

because emptyString doesn't have any characters. But even if I put an arbitrary constant in, it doesn't replace the non-letters with this arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't how you replace characters in a Java string. In Java, strings are immutable, so you can't set any given index. Additionally, the `charAt()` method doesn't and can't do anything to the string you're calling it on - all it does is just return the `char` at that position. Lastly, you probably shouldn't be using `void` - return the `String` with characters replaced at the end of the method, then use the return value. You can accomplish this by iterating through your initial `string` and build a new `string`, using the static `isUpperCase` method of the `Character` class:

```
public static String formatPlainText(String sentence) 
{
    String replacedSentence = "";

    for(int i = 0; i< sentence.length() ; i++){
        char ch = sentence.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            replacedSentence += ch;
        }
        else {
            replacedSentence += " ";
        }
    }   

    return replacedSentence;
}
```

If you're going to be using this frequently, or for particularly long `Strings`, you should absolutely use a `StringBuilder` instead - concatenating `String` on a character-by-character basis is deeply inefficient.

Comment: isnt isUpperCase a method of the character class? i.e Character.isUpperCase(char)

Comment: @MauricioTrajano, typo only I guess. :)

Comment: @bumbumpaw Nah, he was right - I'd forgotten and I was using it as a method of the `char` object.

Comment: @furkle, did you also mean to write :
replacedSentence += Character.toString(ch) ??

Comment: @furkle, It doesn't seem to work with either correction.

Comment: @furkle It's creating new lines like "\n" does, not is not replacing the non-letter characters or creating spaces.

Comment: @hello I've tested this and it's working fine. Did you just copy-paste this into part of your pre-existing method? You shouldn't be using a void return type - you need to return a new string and use that return value as your new, lower-case-replaced string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that arguments in Java are passed as values, not as references, and in this case the String is an immutable object, i.e. an String cannot be changed, when you do a concatenation or replace you're effectively creating a new String.

What I would recommend is to modify your code a little bit to return the new String that was built.

```
public static String formatPlaintext(String sentence){

  String sentenceUpper = sentence.toUpperCase();
  System.out.println(sentenceUpper);

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder;
  for(int i = 0; i< sentenceUpper.length() ; i++){
      char ch = sentenceUpper.charAt(i);
      if(ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z'){

       builder.append(' ');

      } else {
         builder.append(ch);  
      }
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I can't use String Builders.